# Why does Rogue say she is "half-alien?

Tags: marvel, x-men, rogue

I'm reading the Chris Claremont/Frank Miller trade paperback *Wolverine*.

I'm familiar with many of the basic X-Men characters, although mostly from movies, TV, and video games, rather than the X-Men comics themselves (although I've read a handful).

On the last page of the reprinting of *The Uncanny X-Men* #172, Rogue insists on joining Wolverine.

When Wolverine asks about the poison (Viper had just poisoned all of the X-Men in Japan including Logan and Rogue, with only Storm avoiding it).  Rogue responds by saying:

> Ah'm half-alien, remember?  It wasn't so effective on me.

What does she mean by this?  I thought Rogue's parents were hippies.

Comment: By this point, she had absorbed Carol Danvers, who was effectively half-Kree - but I don't know why/how absorbing all of Danvers' psyche would give her physical attributes as well.

Comment: @phantom42 Isn't Rogue's mutant power all about absorbing the physical attributes?

Comment: @Izkata - it was about absorbing mutant powers, I think. Not exactly sure about whether being half-Kree counts as one.

Comment: @DVK If the Kree side is how Ms. Marvel flew, then yes - that's how Rogue got her flight ability.  Otherwise, I couldn't say.

Comment: @izkata, as far as I can recall, she has absorbed powers, life-force and memories/personality - but never physical attributes that were *not* power-based (e.g: claws, steel skin).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Rogue's statement that she was half-alien was indeed a reference to the [Kree genetic traits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carol_Danvers#Powers_and_abilities) she absorbed from Carol Danvers when she completely and permanently absorbed Danver's power set in Avengers Annual 10 (November 1981, Marvel Comics).**

In the case of Danver's powers, they were part of a transformation and absorption of Kree-DNA and would have been necessary for Rogue to replicate in order to utilize Danver's Kree powers. In the past, Rogue's powers were triggered by touch and without a conscious control of those abilities. In modern depictions, she is able to take on the powers of anyone she has ever imprinted their abilities within her mutable DNA.

Rogue's absorption of an entity's powers can include physical transformations such as the Osmium skin of Colossus, the bone claws of Wolverine or the shadow-cloaking abilities of Nightcrawler.

[image]

When she utilizes the physical attributes of a being, she will often take on the physical characteristics of the being whose powers she is using. In the following image, she is utilizing an imprint of the Hulk she acquired in the past and becomes large and green in the process.

[image]

Comment: so cooooool... awesome pics with the answer @Thaddeus